# Rails 4/AJAX GET data from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I posted a very poor question about this earlier, so I am reposting and making it MVCE.

I'm building a messaging service with Rails and AJAX. So far I can submit a message through a form, it will update in the HTML DOM, an AJAX POST method will send it to the controller, and the controller will save it in the database.

Now I need to add an AJAX method that will GET the message that was just submitted -- so that other users (in other browsers) will be able to view it.

Currently, and this is a hack job way of doing it, in my JS code I set a timeout that calls an AJAX GET function every half second. Is there a better way to do this -- as in, once the controller saves the message can it call the AJAX function? The AJAX code looks like this:

```
function retrieveMessages(){
  var message;
  <%debugger%>
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"<%= messages_get_path %>",
    dataType:"json",
    data: { what_goes_here: "blah" }, //this is the part I do not understand -- see below
    success:function(data){
      message = data;
      console.log(data)
    }
  });

  setTimeout(retrieveMessages, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  //get messages
  setTimeout(retrieveMessages, 500);
... more irrelevant
```

The line `data: { what_goes_here: "blah" }` doesn't make sense to me. What is the syntax for the controller to send data back to be stored into `data:`? Furthermore, from the console I can see that `what_goes_here` is being passed as a parameter to the controller -- again this doesn't make sense to me.

My route looks like this `get 'messages/get', :to => 'messages#get'` (this might be incorrect?)

`rake routes` shows

```
  messages_get GET    /messages/get(.:format)        messages#get
```

And as of now, I don't have anything in my controller other than a `respond_to` because at this point I'm just trying to call the controller. What is the syntax to send data back to the AJAX method?

```
def get
  debugger
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @variable} //is this @variable being passed to the AJAX call?
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

This makes more sense to me... the AJAX method simply calls the `def get` function. The `def get` function then finds the message in the database, and stores it in an instance variable. Subsequently, I can add some Javascript code that will insert it into the DOM. However I must have something wrong in my routing because I'm getting (in the console) `http://localhost:3000/messages/get 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You mean other users with other browsers should see the message as soon as it was submitted?

Comment: @NicNilov correct, is there an entirely different way this should be done?

Comment: `data: { what_goes_here: "blah" }` is for supplying extra parameters with the request, as you have noticed yourself. Since you seem to not need extra parameters for refreshing the messages, you can just delete this line.

Comment: @NicNilov where is the data stored in the AJAX method? And what is the syntax for the controller to send it back? Can it just be an instance variable? Actually that makes sense, the AJAX just calls the action, which finds an instance variable in the DB, and then the JS code inserts it into the DOM

Comment: To send data back from controller you usually render a `<action name>.json.erb` template. This results in piece of JSON being sent back as the result of your ajax call. It will be available as an argument to your `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing, as you suspect, is not effective. The more users are online the more will be load from these refreshing requests, most of them probably returning no new data.

You should consider more active way of notifying your browsers about changes on the server. One option is to use [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable).